# Liferay FileEntry UUID Source

Tags: liferay, media, portlet, uuid, documents

I'm still new to Liferay and using Liferay 6.2

the problem here is that i need to find the Jar and class that is generating the UUID for the uploaded files for documents and media portlet.

example : /documents/10180/13012/something/d311151a-4420-4245-ac51-5fc02da94e95

The UUID is : d311151a-4420-4245-ac51-5fc02da94e95

After digging for a few days, i found the class DeterminateKeyGenerator but after checking, it is not the one generating(or i believe it is not generating).

Any tips or pointers on this?

Thanks!

Comment: just gave it a quick look, maybe [this](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/553adad92d68c0ebd8ee4da73fa3d97d54775dc5/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/uuid/PortalUUIDImpl.java) ist what you are looking for

Comment: `PortalUUIDUtil.generate` is the method which generates it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [PortalUUIDImpl.java](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/553adad92d68c0ebd8ee4da73fa3d97d54775dc5/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/uuid/PortalUUIDImpl.java) for the implementation